# How to add video from camera roll to app on Xcode (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, video, camera

I want users to be able to import a video from their camera roll, edit it, then save the video to their camera roll. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, firstly you need to ask user's permissions like this:

```
AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(forMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) { response in
    if response {
        //access granted
    } else {

    }
}

//Photos
let photos = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()
if photos == .notDetermined {
    PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({status in
        if status == .authorized{
            ...
        } else {}
    })
}
```

Then you need to put some description about why you want it in plist file as shown bellow:

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>You can take photos</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>You can select photos to attach it on this app.</string>
```

About edit the video, it is a very subjective subject. What kind of change do you need to do? And depending on what you want to do it could be so much complex.

Later save to camera roll, I got a code example that downloads a file and saves it to camera roll:

```
import AssetsLibrary

...
...

func downloadVideoToCameraRoll() {

// Local variable pointing to the local file path for the downloaded video
var localFileUrl: String?

// A closure for generating the local file path for the downloaded video. This will be pointing to the Documents directory with a unique UDID file name.
let destination: (NSURL, NSHTTPURLResponse) -> (NSURL) = {
    (temporaryURL, response) in

    if let directoryURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0] as? NSURL {
        let finalPath = directoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("\(NSUUID()).\(response.suggestedFilename!)")
        localFileUrl = finalPath.absoluteString
        return finalPath
    }

    return temporaryURL
}

// The media post which should be downloaded
let postURL = NSURL(string: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/" + "952201134785549382_250131908" + "?access_token=" + InstagramEngine.sharedEngine().accessToken)!

// Then some magic happens that turns the postURL into the videoURL, which is the actual url of the video media:
let videoURL = NSURL(string: "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfp1/t50.2886-16/11104555_1603400416544760_416259564_s.mp4")!

// Download starts
let request = Alamofire.download(.GET, videoURL, destination)

// Completion handler for the download
request.response { (request, response, data, error) -> Void in
    if let path = localFileUrl {
        let isVideoCompatible = UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(path)
        println("bool: \(isVideoCompatible)") // This logs out "bool: false"

        let library = ALAssetsLibrary()

        library.writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(NSURL(string: path), completionBlock: { (url, error) -> Void in
            // Done! Go check your camera roll
        })
    }
}
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: it says "expected declaration" when I add it to my code, why am I getting this error? :(